# after merge in gitlab how automatically push to GitHub

Tags: github, gitlab-ci

in GitLab if branch merge into master then I want to push automatically to GitHub how it is possible

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab has an automated way of providing this. In your Gitlab repository, go to
Settings->Repository->Mirroring repositories.

Enter the Github repository with your username included.  i.e.  https://username@github.com/group/project.git

Set the Mirror direction to Push.

Use a GitHub personal access token as your password.

Answer (score 0):

At the server level (meaning on gitlab.com side), you would need to register [a webhook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) or use a [GitLab integration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/) in order to cal an external listener/service to do the push to GitHub on each GitLab push event.

Or, similarly  to [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), you can execute commands directly on GitLab server through a GitLab-CI pipeline.
But making a GitLab pipeline work with other services might not be trivial (see [issue 3835](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/3835))

---

So the other approach is on the client side (easier to do, but harder to deploy to each client, since it is no longer centralized on the server side)

You can simply configure your local Git repository setting to push to both GitLab and GitHub in one `git push` command.

```
git remote set-url --add --push origin git@gitlab.com:<user>/my-project.git
git remote set-url --add --push origin git@github.com:<user>/my-project.git
```

But that would apply to *any* push, not just master (and not just on merge)

For just master, you can define a new remote:

```
git remote add all 
git remote set-url --add --push all git@gitlab.com:<user>/my-project.git
git remote set-url --add --push all git@github.com:<user>/my-project.git

git branch --set-upstream-to=all master
```

That way, only `master` will push by default to both GitLab and GitHub.

Or, still locally, you can define a [post-merge hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge), as suggested by [Polygnome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1360803/polygnome) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61862946/after-merge-in-gitlab-how-automatically-push-to-github/61863173?noredirect=1#comment109419355_61863173):

It will:

- control which branch is being merged into
- do the GitHub push.

That only works if the local user is doing the merge though.

Comment: What about setting up a post-merge git hook to automatically push to GitHub when a merge into master occurs?

Comment: @Polygnome if the merge occurs locally, yes. If it is done by someone else, a local hook would not work.

Comment: Sure, but your local solutions already depend on everyone setting that up correctly. And hooks have the added advantage that you can even include them in the repo itself.

Comment: @Polygnome I agree. Although even if you add the hook in the repo itself, it won't be active unless the user cloning the repository sets the hook explicitly through `git config` command.

Comment: thanks @VonC,,,  the problem is in gitlab pipeline failed for some --prod build .. but it is working in gihub for CI deploy... so my Project set on gitlab.... so my planning is whenever PR merge into master then only it redirect to GitHub and then it will be directly deploy from GitHub

Comment: using mirroring any possibility ..?

Comment: @SHAILESH Please edit your question with more details about your current GitLab-CI pipeline.